WebAssembly support for Electron Application
Does WebAssembly support Chromium web browser which is the backend browser for an Electron application? The website mentions that it does support Chrome which is similar to Chromium

Yeah, you can use WebAssembly in Electron apps :) I believe the latest Electron version uses Chrome 124, so all the features listed in https://webassembly.org/features/ should be supported.
